# Force autoloading of a class without having the name

Tags: php, oop

I'd like to have access to all classes that are in the context of my currently executing script. Unfortunately, the framework I am using is aggressive with its use of autoloading, and purposely defers loading of classes along the execution path.

How can I, without knowing the names of classes, force all classes that have a registered `_autoload()` function to either load, so that I can access them with `get_declared_classes`, or get their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the autoload functions were added to `spl_autoload_register()` you should look at [`spl_autoload_functions()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php).

---

Alternatively you could force the invocation of all registered autoloaders with [`spl_autoload_call()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-call.php).